# Problema no na classe de Controller JSP

Tags: java, mysql, aplicação-web, jsp, controller

Olá, preciso de ajuda, estou com o problema no meu sistema quando envio um comando de editar. Quando eu clico no botão de editar a linha da tabela que eu desejo, a tela fica branca e não mostra as opções para editar. Na URL mostra que o campos estão passando corretamente, porém a tela não compila.

[image: Campos na URL da imagem]

Meu JSP está assim, quando clico no botão de editar ele envia uma action para a classe FuncionarioListaController.

```
 <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>RG</th>
                                <th>CPF</th>
                                <th>Cargo</th>
                                <th>Setor</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach items="${funcionarios}" var="funcionario">

                                <tr>


                                    <td class="center"><c:out value="${funcionario.id}" /></td>
                                    <td class="center"><c:out value="${funcionario.nome}" /></td>
                                    <td class="center"><c:out value="${funcionario.rg}" /></td>
                                    <td class="center"><c:out value="${funcionario.cpf}" /></td>
                                    <td class="center"><c:out value="${funcionario.cargo}" /></td>
                                    <td class="center"><c:out value="${funcionario.sigla_setor}" /></td>

                                    <td class="center"><a class="btn btn-info"
                                        href="FuncionarioListaController?action=editar&id=<c:out value="${funcionario.id}"/>">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i> Editar
                                    </a> <a class="btn btn-danger"
                                        href="FuncionarioListaController?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${funcionario.id}"/>">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i>
                                            Deletar
                                    </a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

A classe FuncionarioListaController se encontra assim:

```
@WebServlet("/FuncionarioListaController")
public class FuncionarioListaController extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final String FUNCIONARIO_EDITADO = "/FuncionarioEditado.jsp";
public static final String EDITAR = "/FuncionarioEditar.jsp";
public static final String TABELA = "/VerFuncionario.jsp";
private FuncionarioDAO funcionarioDAO;
private Funcionario funcionario;

/**
* @throws IllegalAccessException
* @throws InstantiationException
* @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
*/
public FuncionarioListaController() throws InstantiationException, 
IllegalAccessException {
super();
funcionarioDAO = new FuncionarioDAO();
funcionario = new Funcionario();
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
* @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
*      response)
*/
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

String forward = "";
String action = request.getParameter("action");
try {
if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
    forward = TABELA;
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    funcionarioDAO.deletarFuncionario(id);
    request.setAttribute("funcionarios", funcionarioDAO.todosFuncionarios());
} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")) {
    forward = EDITAR;
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Funcionario funcionario = funcionarioDAO.buscarFuncionarioId(id);

    funcionarioDAO.atualizarFuncionario(funcionario);
    request.setAttribute("funcionario", funcionario);
}

else {
    forward = TABELA;
    request.setAttribute("funcionarios", funcionarioDAO.todosFuncionarios());
}
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
view.forward(request, response);
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
}

/**
* @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
*      response)
*/
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

funcionario.setNome(request.getParameter("nome"));
funcionario.setRg(request.getParameter("rg"));
funcionario.setCpf(request.getParameter("cpf"));
funcionario.setCargo(request.getParameter("cargo"));
funcionario.setSigla_setor(request.getParameter("sigla_setor"));

Integer idFuncionario = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

String id = Integer.toString(idFuncionario);
try {
if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
    funcionarioDAO.adicionarFuncionario(funcionario);
} else {
    funcionario.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    funcionarioDAO.atualizarFuncionario(funcionario);
}

RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(FUNCIONARIO_EDITADO);
request.setAttribute("funcionarios", funcionarioDAO.todosFuncionarios());
view.forward(request, response);
}catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
}
```

O funcionárioDAO assim:

```
@Override
public void atualizarFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario) throws 
ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
try(Connection conn = ConnectionSQL.conectar()) {
    String query = "UPDATE Funcionario "
            + "SET nome=?, rg=?, cpf=?, cargo=?, sigla_setor=? "
            + "WHERE id=?";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, funcionario.getNome());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, funcionario.getRg());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, funcionario.getCpf());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, funcionario.getCargo());
    preparedStatement.setString(5, funcionario.getSigla_setor());
    preparedStatement.setInt(6, funcionario.getId());
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    preparedStatement.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@Override
public List<Funcionario> todosFuncionarios() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
SQLException {
List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new ArrayList<>();
Connection conn = ConnectionSQL.conectar();
String query = "SELECT id, nome, rg, cpf, cargo, sigla_setor FROM 
Funcionario";
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
while (resultSet.next()) {
    funcionarios.add(resultSetToFuncionario(resultSet));
}

return funcionarios;
}


 @Override
 public Funcionario buscarFuncionarioId(Integer id) throws 
 ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
try (Connection conn = ConnectionSQL.conectar()){
    String query = "SELECT id, nome, rg, cpf, cargo, sigla_setor FROM Funcionario WHERE id = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
    preparedStatement.execute();
}  catch (SQLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque você usa o método atualizarFuncionario() antes de ir para a tela de edição dos dados desse funcionário?
Essa etapa você apenas deve ser direcionado para a tela de edição e a partir dela você submete os dados para atualizar.
E no seu buscarFuncionarioId(id) você não está retornando o Funcionário e sim null. Você precisa criar um Funcionario com os dados vindo do banco de dados e retorná-lo.

```
} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")) {
   forward = EDITAR;
   Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
   Funcionario funcionario = funcionarioDAO.buscarFuncionarioId(id);
   /*AQUI!!!*/
   funcionarioDAO.atualizarFuncionario(funcionario);
   request.setAttribute("funcionario", funcionario);
}
```

Comment: Isso amigão, eu tinha esquecido de clonar a branche certa e algumas informações estavam desatualizadas. Obrigado pela ajuda! Vou comentar as alterações que fiz :)

Comment: Ok! Depois vota na minha resposta como útil e coloca como resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui corrigir fazendo algumas alterações.

Primeiro na classe FuncionarioDAO, onde estava dando retorno null no buscarporID:

```
@Override
public Funcionario buscarFuncionarioId(Funcionario funcionario) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Funcionario retorno = null;
    try (Connection conn = ConnectionSQL.conectar()){
        String query = "SELECT id, nome, rg, cpf, cargo, sigla_setor FROM Funcionario WHERE id = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        preparedStatement.setInt(1, funcionario.getId());
        ResultSet resultado = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        if (resultado.next()) {
            retorno = new Funcionario();
            retorno.setId(resultado.getInt("id"));
            retorno.setNome(resultado.getString("nome"));
            retorno.setRg(resultado.getString("rg"));
            retorno.setCpf(resultado.getString("cpf"));
            retorno.setCargo(resultado.getString("cargo"));
            retorno.setSigla_setor(resultado.getString("sigla_setor"));
        }   

    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Em seguida na classe FuncionárioListaController():

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String forward = "";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    try {
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
        forward = TABELA;
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        funcionarioDAO.deletarFuncionario(id);
        request.setAttribute("funcionarios", funcionarioDAO.todosFuncionarios());
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editar")) {
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
        f.setId(id);
        Funcionario funcionario = funcionarioDAO.buscarFuncionarioId(f);
        forward = EDITAR;
        funcionarioDAO.atualizarFuncionario(funcionario);
        request.setAttribute("funcionario", funcionario);
    } else {
        forward = TABELA;
        request.setAttribute("funcionarios", funcionarioDAO.todosFuncionarios());
    }
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```